# SIgnal R - Calling method with Single Client

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

When i call the displayRegMessage() method from Controller, it is being called by all the Clients. I only want this method to be called to a single Client.

Controller :-

```
 public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ....
             var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hub>();

            context.Clients.All.displayRegMessage("1");
            return View();
        }
```

View :-

```
    var payrollHub = jq.connection.payrollHub;

    payrollHub.client.displayRegMessage = function (msg) {
       ....
        jq(".msg").html(msg);
    };
    jq.connection.hub.start();
```

I am using `Signal R` as an Update Progress Bar. It is working fine. But If 2 computers have opened same page & if i call the Method from 1 computer then it is also invoked & seen playing in the second computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a group (which could be a single client), but you have to apply an id for the group.

```
public class PayrollHub : Hub
{
    public void Join(string groupId)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupId);
    }
}
```

To join the group you do something like the below, where groupId is a unique value (string in this case) for the client, such as a user name:

```
        jq.connection.hub.start().done(() => {
            jq.connection.payrollHub.server.join(groupId);
        });
```

In your controller action call it like this, were groupId again is the unique group id (such as a user name):

```
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PayrollHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.Group(groupId).displayRegMessage("1");
```

Comment: Should the 3 ids in the above 3 blocks of code match??

Comment: In Controller, I will do like this :- `context.Clients.Group(HttpContext.Session.SessionID).displayRegMessage("1");` But how will i get `Session Id` in the View Jquery?

Comment: @Anup yes the id will be your group's id, so if they don't match then you could be trying to sending signals to a group that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Anup If you are wanting to take the approach of using the session id then you could add it to the ViewBag and then render it into a constructor for your javascript view model, however using this approach wouldn't work for the same client using 2 different browsers at the same time.

Comment: So what will be the right approach?? WHat should i use as `groupid`?

Comment: @Anup as mentioned above, one suggestion is to use a user id as the group id such as one from a database, then the progress bar will only display for that user. This is obviously only a suggestion based on If you are storing user information. If you are using windows authentication then you could instead use information from the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`

Comment: I preferred to go with `Session Id`, by storing it in `hidden` field & then getting it in JQuery.. Thanks for Help..!